# { "error": "Malformed request: POST /v1/models/text_model" } Tensorflow Serving

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am Using Colab for text Classification, it is Multilabel text classification model

```
 import json

# inputFeature1 
inputFeature1="¿Tiene el arte que gustar a todos? Pues no"  

#inputFeature2
inputFeature2="Una imagen del último día de la exposición ded"


#inputFeature3  
inputFeature3="marabilias"



instances=[{"inputFeature1":[inputFeature1],"inputFeature2=":[inputFeature2],"inputFeature3":[inputFeature3]}]

data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": instances})
print('Data: {} ... {}'.format(data[:50], data[len(data)-52:]))
print(data)
print(requests.post('http://localhost:8501/v1/models/text_model', data=data).content.decode())
```

## Error is

```
{ "error": "Malformed request: POST /v1/models/text_model" } Tensorflow Serving
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the model signature, I believe the issue is with your `instances=` statement.
Change it to:
`instances=[{"inputFeature1":inputFeature1,"inputFeature2=":inputFeature2,"inputFeature3":inputFeature3}]`

You were passing the feature value as a list [] rather than just the values. 
When we pass the values for `json.dumps`, we need to send a list of dicts.

The value of `dicts` need not be a list.

Also, make sure you are checking your model signature for the data type for input features. You can use `saved_model_cli show --dir /path/to/your/model --all` rfom command line.